# cant install rhc openshift client on ubuntu 11.10 64 bit

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems, openshift

Can anyone help me out, ive got Ruby 1.9.1 installed and Ruby Gems 1.8, here is the error message:

```
~$ sudo gem install rhc
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rhc:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

rake1.8 RUBYARCHDIR=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-rest-0.0.14/lib RUBYLIBDIR=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-rest-0.0.14/lib
sh: rake1.8: not found
```

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-rest-0.0.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-rest-0.0.14/ext/gem_make.out

Comment: have you tried sudo gem install rake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on Michael Frederick comment, for my Linux Mint 12 Lisa 32 bits, i have the same error, the final solution for install Ruby apps to manage Openshift cloud its the follow:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8
sudo apt-get install gem
sudo apt-get install rubygems
sudo gem install json_pure
sudo gem install rake
sudo gem install rhc
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you might want to try installing the Ruby Version Manager (RVM) package instead of the standard ruby packages which tie you to a specific version of ruby.  You should look at the bottom of this page where I list some directions on how to install the rvm and rhc on ubuntu.

https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/install-the-client-tools